# Why my view is not found in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on mezzanine rest api and adding some more views to be able to work easily. I coded one view and made its serializer but when trying to hit from postman, I am getting error not found 404

`Views.py`

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_site_record(request):
    serializer = SiteModelSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class SiteModelSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    tagline = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    domain = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Site.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

`urls.py`

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'pages', PageViewSet)
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet)
router.register(r'categories', CategoryViewSet)
# router.register(r'create_site', create_site_record, 'sitess')
router.register(r'site', SiteViewSet, SiteViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}))


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', create_site_record), # I have tried registering this view in router also but no luck
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    url(r'^oauth2/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

I am trying to hit this endpoint : `http://localhost:8000/api/create_site/`
with payload : `{
    "title": "Test",
    "tagling": "sdhjshjd",
    "domain": "test:8000"
}`

Getting error : `Not Found: /api/create_site/`
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a problem with your url path. There is no need to have the digit capture for a create endpoint, since that is generally used for referencing an existing object. Try changing the path to `url(r'^create/$', create_site_record)` and send the POST request to`http://localhost:8000/api/create/`.

Comment: Still getting error: `Not Found: /create_site/
[03/Aug/2016 09:04:56] "POST /create_site/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1697`

Comment: Since its a mezzanine project and I am running on top of this mezzanine rest api framework and its registeres url pattern has `    url("^api/", include("mezzanine_api.urls"))`

Comment: Ah ok, then the api part was correct. I accidentally had create_site in the url. The updated one should work.

Comment: Hey @rurp one thing when I try to register my api on router why doesn't it work there?

Comment: Double check that you changed ```create_site``` to ```create``` in the router.register. If that doesn't fix it then make sure your ```include``` statements are correct. Is the urls.py you posted above from mezzanine_api?

Comment: `urls.py` is from `mezzanine rest-api` and I have updated created_site to create . Do I need to incude the `/$` part also?

Comment: The router looks fine in that case. Try commenting out the ```create``` url pattern. That path is already included in router.urls and might be messing something up.

Comment: Tried all that. No luck

Comment: If that doesn't fix it then everything seems fine and there's probably a simple typo somewhere. If you edit your post to add your current url file I'll take a look and maybe see something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119037/discussion-between-nikhil-parmar-and-rurp).